# ReferenceError: $ is not defined jQuery Colorbox

Tags: jquery, colorbox

few days ago I was using jQuery colorbox it was working perfectly fine however after I upgraded to jQuery v1.11.0 it suddenly stopped working completely.

Using firebug to check for any errors I found the following;

> ReferenceError: $ is not defined $(document).ready(function(){

This code below now acts as a normal href.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" defer="defer"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js" defer="defer"></script>
<script src="https://raw.github.com/jackmoore/colorbox/master/jquery.colorbox-min.js" type="text/javascript" defer="defer"></script>
<link id="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/popup/box/colorbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("a.popup").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:680, innerHeight:401});
    });
    </script>

<a class="popup" href="/core/ajax/status.php?ID=143" title="Status">View Status</a>
```

Comment: Please jsfiddle provide!

Comment: Drop the use of defer, as the answers have suggested. Also you can't reference JS files from GitHub because it returns a text/plain mime type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you have [defered](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer) the loading of jQuery, so when your inline script block is executed jQuery is not yet loaded.

The [defer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer) attribute of [script](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element) tells the browser to dealy the loading of script till the document is parsed

Don't defer the loading of jQuery

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.github.com/jackmoore/colorbox/master/jquery.colorbox-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

---

Another choice is to make your script also to execute in a deferred manner by moving it to a separate js file and including it as a deferred resource like

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" defer="defer"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js" defer="defer"></script>
<script src="https://raw.github.com/jackmoore/colorbox/master/jquery.colorbox-min.js" type="text/javascript" defer="defer"></script>
<script src="test.js" defer="defer"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Defer` tells the browser to wait "until it's ready" before executing the javascript in that script block. Usually this is after the DOM has finished loading and document.readyState == 4.

So jquery is not loaded when `$(document).ready` gets called. Remove the defer attribute and everything will work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.popup").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:680, innerHeight:401});
});
</script>
```

Starts after html parser see it! And your scripts with defer attribute is executes when the page has finished parsing.

Solution: Just remove defer attribute from all scripts!